# Change virtual directory on iisnode?

Tags: node.js, iis-8, iisnode

Right now the sites are accessible through the virtual directory named node as said in the docs.

Is there a way to change its name? Or even remove it completely from the URL?

Instead of:

> http://localhost/node/express/myapp/demo

I would like to have:

> http://localhost/express/myapp/demo

Or ideally:

> http://localhost/demo

This last case is how the url looks when using node as a server.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your default website, in IIS, you should see that it added node as a virtual application. you should be able to remove it from there and reconfigure as desired. Just make sure to review the rewrite rules/configuration in the web.config file for the /node/ folder.